# python `IN` module problem (FreeBSD)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to work with sockets and I  have such problem

In code example:

```
setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE,self.listen_address+'\0')
```

I have error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SO_BINDTODEVICE'
```

On Linux machine this attribute is OK but on FreeBSD trere are no any SO_* attributes in module `IN`. What port should I install to resolve this problem on FreeBDS machine?

Python versions on Linux tested:
2.5.4 and 2.6.4;
on FreeBSD:
2.5.5

I can't find anything about this module in my book, and googling keyword `IN` looks like seamless ...

**update:**

I can only bind to address, not to device.

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.bind(("eth0",3040))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>> s.bind(("192.168.33.152",3040))
>>> s.close()
```

**update 2:**

... but I'm working with broadcast packets. I'm trying to write daemon which acts like DHCP server. 
If I bind to address would I catch broadcast packets? And if I'll set promiscuous mode on?

Comment: Next time, try running: `pydoc MODULE_NAME` in your terminal before googling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option is not standard and is not supported on FreeBSD. Why can't you just use regular [`bind(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bind&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html) for assigning local address/interface?

#### Edit:

Take a look at the [socket object docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket-objects).
Here's an [example](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.1/lib/socket-example.html).

#### Edit 2:

You didn't say what exactly you are trying to achieve, so assuming regular TCP/IP client-server.

IP, being a network-layer protocol (vs. for example, Ethernet, which is a data-link protocol), is not concerned with devices, but *addresses*. The idea is that you *don't need* to bind to a device - the OS takes care of mapping addresses to devices, and maintains a *routing table*. The only time you need explicit relationship between a socket and a device is when working with *broadcast* and *multicast*, where mapping between addresses and interfaces is not obvious.

Each network interface known to TCP/IP stack is assigned an IP address (see [`ifconfig(8)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html)). Bind your socket to that IP address and you'll be all set.

Hope this helps.

#### Edit 3:

Have you looked into `SO_BROADCAST` option? Also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/) about *raw sockets*.

Comment: How can use it in my python program for binding socket?

Comment: ... but I'm working with broadcast packets. I'm trying to write daemon which acts like DHCP server. 
If I bind to address would I catch broadcast packets? And if I'll set promiscuous mode on?