# How to set the socket type and the protocol of a socket using create_connection in python?

Tags: python, sockets, types, protocols

I want to use `socket.create_connection()` to set a source address in a ping implementation in python.

But how can I then set the type and the protocol? Because, before, I did:

```
icmp = socket.getprotobyname("icmp") 
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)
```

But now, I do:

```
src_addr = socket.gethostbyname(src_addr) 
dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(dest_addr) 
my_socket = socket.create_connection(dest_addr, socket.getdefaulttimeout(), src_addr)
```

Is there something like `my_socket.setproto()`? I haven't found such a function in the documentation.

Thank you, 
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

create_connection will create a TCP connection, so it is not going to do what you want. You need to use raw sockets as in the example you gave yourself. Why do you want to switch to use socket.create_connection?

Comment: First, thank you for your help!
I want to set a source address and the only way I found is to use create_connection.
I want to do the equivalent of
    ping -S x.x.x.x y.y.y.y

Comment: Sorry, rather late answer. Have a look at this solution. I think this does the exact thing you tried to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python