# How to set a source address for ICMP messages in Python?

Tags: python, ping, icmp, source-address

I'm trying to change [this implementation of ping](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/10/30/python-ping/) so I can set a different source address for the messages.
What I want to do is exactly the same thing that the `-S` option of the original ping can do:

```
ifconfig em0 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 alias
ifconfig em0 10.0.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 alias
ping -c4 -S 10.0.1.1 10.0.2.1
```

This works of course but I would like to do the same thing with Python.

Comment: Where are you getting hung up? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

The sample code you are showing is using a `IPPROTO_ICMP` socket, that can be bound to a specific address using `bind()`.

So, just after the `my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)` line, you can add:

```
my_socket.bind((your_source_address, 0))
```

The second argument in the tuple is the port number, that seems to be ignored by `IPPROTO_ICMP`.

Note that the operating system may not allow you to bind the socket to an arbitrary address, but only a valid address belonging to your host, maybe this is enough for your use case. If you want to set a completely arbitrary source address, you may need to use a `IPPROTO_RAW` socket instead, and then build the whole IP packet header yourself. See this question for some  pointers: [How Do I Use Raw Socket in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it's exactly what I needed. I didn't understand the bind() function this way. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @gcomte If it helped to solve the problem, mark the question as answered, so it could help other people to.

Comment: It doesn't work...
    `socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address`

Comment: @gcomte: this error message means the OS is rejecting the address you are trying to set. Maybe you it does not belong to your host, or maybe it's just because if you set the port number as 1.