# RAW client-server socket python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, raw-sockets

I would like to realize a RAW socket in Python and then send data from the Client to the Server.

Unlike a normal socket I've tried to use the following definition

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
```

but commands as

```
s.listen(1), s.connect()
```

are not working.
I have no clue how to program both the Client.py and the Server.py.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Use Raw Socket in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because a raw socket doesn't utelize the Ethernet/TCP/IP library at all. It's a RAW socket, you're in charge of whatever data you send. You're also in charge of connecting to your peer by sending the right SYN/ACK order.

Traditional sockets is an "abstraction" layer for you to send your payload (data).
Meaning you *connect* your socket to a destination, you tell the *socket* what data to send, assuming you're using a TCP based socket your data will be prepended with a header corresponding to the TCP protocol and version and your data might get segmented based on how much data you're trying to push through.

All this happens automatically with a traditional socket.

This is what a TCP header looks like, roughly (taken out of context but it will give you an idea):

```
   0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Sequence Number                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
   | Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
   |       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                             data                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Note that **data** is what you normally do, but when working with RAW sockets, you need to **send all these information blocks on to your Ethernet cable**.

I could post some code later tonight perhaps if someone doesn't beat me to it, but here's a good short usage example: [How Do I Use Raw Socket in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python)

---

### tl;dr:

You need to build a Ethernet header and a TCP header and add your data to it according to the RFC standard (this might be a good place to start: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793). Then you need to "simply" send that out on to your "socket". There's no magic involved with RAW sockets, you build your header with a source+destination address, and you send your payload out onto the cable hoping you built the packet correctly.

## Answer to comments:

`socket.accept()` - This function is used in traditional sockets to "store" session information (Source:Port -> Destination:Port). This function takes clients from a buffered queue of incoming connection attempts and "activates" them. This does not apply to raw sockets, the reason being is that the abstraction layer from normal sockets is again, not present. Your RAW socket will listen to any incoming **data** (not connections), meaning you're in charge  of receiving first a `SYN` packet which you need to respond with a `SYN-ACK` in which you'll receive a final `ACK`. At this point, you're good to go for sending data between you with the correct information (source port etc).

Here's a good (ASCII) flow-chart of the abstraction layer provided in a **normal socket**:

```
                              +---------+ ---------\      active OPEN  
                              |  CLOSED |            \    -----------  
                              +---------+<---------\   \   create TCB  
                                |     ^              \   \  snd SYN    
                   passive OPEN |     |   CLOSE        \   \           
                   ------------ |     | ----------       \   \         
                    create TCB  |     | delete TCB         \   \       
                                V     |                      \   \     
                              +---------+            CLOSE    |    \   
                              |  LISTEN |          ---------- |     |  
                              +---------+          delete TCB |     |  
                   rcv SYN      |     |     SEND              |     |  
                  -----------   |     |    -------            |     V  
 +---------+      snd SYN,ACK  /       \   snd SYN          +---------+
 |         |<-----------------           ------------------>|         |
 |   SYN   |                    rcv SYN                     |   SYN   |
 |   RCVD  |<-----------------------------------------------|   SENT  |
 |         |                    snd ACK                     |         |
 |         |------------------           -------------------|         |
 +---------+   rcv ACK of SYN  \       /  rcv SYN,ACK       +---------+
   |           --------------   |     |   -----------                  
   |                  x         |     |     snd ACK                    
   |                            V     V                                
   |  CLOSE                   +---------+                              
   | -------                  |  ESTAB  |                              
   | snd FIN                  +---------+                              
   |                   CLOSE    |     |    rcv FIN                     
   V                  -------   |     |    -------                     
 +---------+          snd FIN  /       \   snd ACK          +---------+
 |  FIN    |<-----------------           ------------------>|  CLOSE  |
 | WAIT-1  |------------------                              |   WAIT  |
 +---------+          rcv FIN  \                            +---------+
   | rcv ACK of FIN   -------   |                            CLOSE  |  
   | --------------   snd ACK   |                           ------- |  
   V        x                   V                           snd FIN V  
 +---------+                  +---------+                   +---------+
 |FINWAIT-2|                  | CLOSING |                   | LAST-ACK|
 +---------+                  +---------+                   +---------+
   |                rcv ACK of FIN |                 rcv ACK of FIN |  
   |  rcv FIN       -------------- |    Timeout=2MSL -------------- |  
   |  -------              x       V    ------------        x       V  
    \ snd ACK                 +---------+delete TCB         +---------+
     ------------------------>|TIME WAIT|------------------>| CLOSED  |
                              +---------+                   +---------+
```

## Here's a server example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
#s.bind(("eth1", 0))

# We're putting together an ethernet frame here, 
# NOTE: Not a full TCP frame, this is important to remember!
src_addr = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"
dst_addr = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"
payload = ("["*30)+"PAYLOAD"+("]"*30)
checksum = "\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d"
ethertype = "\x08\x01"

s.send(dst_addr+src_addr+ethertype+payload+checksum)
```

Found some old code that I barely got started on, might come in handy: https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/tree/master/python/Laboratory

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Indeed I will have to create my own packet (header dst address etc) and I intend to do that with Scapy.
But my problem now is that I don't even know what's the code for both client and server to create the socket, without exchange any data.

Comment: Ok, maybe I can create the socket now but I get this error:
    `starting up on 192.168.240.1 port 10000
waiting for a connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rawserve.py", line 20, in <module>
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 122] Operation not supported`

The server is waiting for the client to be connected. How can I do that?

Comment: @m.ridolfi Ignore `.accept()` and everything you know.. Watch my edit to my post.. Again, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python which gives you a CLEAR example of how to set up a server socket, i'll include it in my edit as well.

Comment: Thanks, my problem now is that I can't send the packet. Do you mean that I must write the code to send SYN message or it is automatically done? Can you check my current situation:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672575/cant-send-scapy-packet-over-a-raw-socket-in-python)?

Comment: @m.ridolfi Found my old code as promised: https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/tree/master/python/Laboratory

Answer (score 1):

Raw sockets are connectionless, meaning that listen and accept will not work. Yet, you can use this Python library: [rawsocketpy](https://github.com/AlexisTM/rawsocket_python) it allows using raw sockets on Layer 2 and implements a server like option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from rawsocketpy import RawSocket

sock = RawSocket("wlp2s0", 0xEEFA)
sock.send("some data")
sock.send("personal data", dest="\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF")
```

or the server form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from rawsocketpy import RawRequestHandler, RawAsyncServerCallback
import time

def callback(handler, server):
    print("Testing")
    handler.setup()
    handler.handle()
    handler.finish()

class LongTaskTest(RawRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(self.packet)

    def finish(self):
        print("End")

    def setup(self):
        print("Begin") 

def main():
    rs = RawAsyncServerCallback("wlp2s0", 0xEEFA, LongTaskTest, callback)
    rs.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The last commit message is "Drop Python3 compatibility and in wait for a new to_bytes function" which does not inspire confidence.